# Angular 2 Issue: Error while typing "npm start" in Git Bash

Tags: angular, npm

I am a beginner in Angular 2. I am going through a Udemy course entitled "Learning Angular 2 by Building 12 Apps." I am facing issues with setting up Angular 2. I have done everything shown in the video entitled "Angular 2 Quickstart Setup  Explanation." But when I type "npm start" in Git Bash, I am getting this error:

```
> a2website@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Kanon\Desktop\exercise fies\learn angular by building apps\a2website
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable t      o type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! a2website@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the a2website@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-31T14_25_27_937Z-debug.log
```

Here is the error log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~prestart: a2website@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: a2website@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Kanon\Desktop\exercise fies\learn angular by building apps\a2website\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Kanon\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Kanon\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Users\Kanon\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\erl9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\GTK2-bundle\bin;C:\Program Files\gettext-iconv\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Kanon\Desktop\exercise fies\learn angular by building apps\a2website
10 silly lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ' ]
11 silly lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle a2website@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: a2website@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid a2website@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Kanon\Desktop\exercise fies\learn angular by building apps\a2website
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error a2website@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the a2website@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

You can find my project files here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BlxYt29j7QkGrAdR7Jovid34f5kwXaeE

Please, help me to find the solution. I cannot proceed further to the course until the issue is solved.

Comment: upgrade your angular versions to angular 4 and then upgrade rxjs to 5.4

Comment: As the others have mentioned, your project is outdated. I'd highly recommended keeping your project at the latest, stable, major version (5+ as if now). If you're trying to use someone else's project you have chosen something that hasn't been maintained for a long time, and I'd suggest you either start from a fresh Angular CLI (5+) project or ensure the seed/boilerplate you use does

Comment: @Z.Bagley OK. I understand. As I am a beginner in Angular, should I go for a new course featuring Angular 5 and leaving the current Angular 2 course? Would you please suggest me a good video course on the latest version of Angular?

Comment: @john I don't use any video tutorials myself, prefer written blogs. I'd highly recommend at least running through the Angular - Tour of Heroes before you use any external guides if you're just starting. A few hours of reading and coding and you'll have a strong foundation, and know how to look for more specific vlogs to get the job done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgrade your Angular (5.2 already).
Run: `yarn add @angular/cli`.
Then, navigate to a directory and run `ng new <project-name>`

That's it,
Angular is configured.

Also,
I recommend going through Angular.io documentation and Getting started. It's good and informative.

Comment: OK. I understand. As I am a beginner in Angular, should I go for a new course featuring Angular 5 and leaving the current Angular 2 course? If the answer is yes, would you please suggest me a good video course on the latest version of Angular?

Comment: Absolutely yes.
As I said in my answer, you can read Angular's Quick Start:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.
It helped me a lot.
If you mind paying, Pluralsight has lots of good courses.